# JavaFX - ListView scroll one by one element when clicking down or up in the scrollbar

Tags: listview, javafx

I have a ListView with 16 items. When I scroll it (either using the arrows or with the mouse) of the default ListView ScrollBar, it scrolls half item.

What I need is to scroll by one item (when clicking the arrows or scrolling with the mouse) so the list never show half items. Is there any way to do this?
Here's my code:

```
public void start(Stage primaryStage) throws IOException {
    ListView<String> lstRequestOpt = new ListView<>();
    List<String> x = new ArrayList<>();
    for(int i = 0; i < 30; i++) {
        x.add("item " + i);
    }
    ObservableList<String> items = FXCollections.observableArrayList(x);
    lstRequestOpt.setItems(items);
    Scene scene = new Scene(lstRequestOpt);
    primaryStage.setScene(scene);
    primaryStage.show();
}
```

Here's the output image:
[ListView with half items](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsB2f.png)

What I'm trying to achieve here is that the elements are shown complete and not like int he picture:

- When scrolling
- When moving the scroll bar with the mouse
- When clicking the arrows in the scroll bar

Is there any way to do this?

**UPDATE:**

I could manage to create a method that will print something whenever the scroll or the arrows are used, even if it's the smallest scrolling. Now i need to find a way to set the value of movement in the scroll and integrate it with the ListView. I'll continue to work on it. Here's the code:

```
for (Node node : lstRequestOpt.lookupAll(".scroll-bar")) {
        if (node instanceof ScrollBar) {
            final ScrollBar bar = (ScrollBar) node;
            bar.valueProperty().addListener(new ChangeListener<Number>() {
                @Override
                public void changed(ObservableValue<? extends Number> value, Number oldValue, Number newValue) {
                    if ((double) oldValue < (double) newValue) {
                        System.out.println("UP");
                    } else {
                        System.out.println("DOWN");
                    }
                }
            });
        }
    }
```

Thanks to everyone that is helping me.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem. that said: basically, you can lookup the scrollbar and set its unit increment

Answer (score 1):

I had a very hacky way. Not sure whether this suits you or not. But the end intension is to not scroll px by px.

The idea is to listen the value property of the vertical scroll bar and set the ListView scroll based on the current scroll bar value. The below approach can give you some inputs. One drawback is that I need to rely on VirtualFlow.

```
import com.sun.javafx.scene.control.skin.VirtualFlow;
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.collections.FXCollections;
import javafx.collections.ObservableList;
import javafx.scene.AccessibleAttribute;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.ListView;
import javafx.scene.control.ScrollBar;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class ListViewScrollDemo  extends Application {
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws Exception {
        StackPane root = new StackPane();
        Scene sc = new Scene(root, 600, 200);
        stage.setScene(sc);
        stage.show();
        List<String> items = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 1; i < 21; i++) {
            items.add("Item "+i);
        }
        ObservableList<String> itemList = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
        itemList.addAll(items);
        ScrollListView<String> list = new ScrollListView<>();
        list.setItems(itemList);
        root.getChildren().add(list);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Application.launch(args);
    }

    class ScrollListView<T> extends ListView<T>{
        boolean firstRender = false;
        public ScrollListView() {
            needsLayoutProperty().addListener((obs,old,needsLayout)->{
                if(!firstRender && !needsLayout){
                    firstRender = true;
                    VirtualFlow<?> virtualFlow = (VirtualFlow<?>) lookup(".virtual-flow");

                    // Keeping vertical scrollBar node reference and tweaking the vertical scroll bar behavior to
                    // scroll by row and not by pixel.
                    ScrollBar vScrollBar = (ScrollBar) queryAccessibleAttribute(AccessibleAttribute.VERTICAL_SCROLLBAR);
                    vScrollBar.valueProperty().addListener((obs1, oldVal1, newVal) -> {
                        int visibleRowCount = virtualFlow.getLastVisibleCell().getIndex()-virtualFlow.getFirstVisibleCell().getIndex();
                        final double scrollVal = newVal.doubleValue();
                        final int size = getItems().size();
                        if (scrollVal < 1.0) {
                            final int virtualRowCount = size - visibleRowCount;
                            final double eachRowBuff = 1d / virtualRowCount;
                            for (int index = 0; index < virtualRowCount; index++) {
                                final double start = eachRowBuff * index;
                                final double end = start + eachRowBuff;
                                if (start <= scrollVal && scrollVal < end) {
                                    scrollTo(index);
                                    vScrollBar.setValue(start);
                                    break;
                                }
                            }
                        } else {
                            scrollTo(size - 1);
                        }
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: nice try (+1 for that :) - but not reliable (at least not in fx11): a) in this exact example, there are "half-lines" due to the fixed size of the stage (vs. letting the scene come up at its pref). b) with more items (say 100) and pref initial, everything seems to work as expected ... c) ... for a while only: there are spurious artefacts f.i. when scrolling up by clicking at the scrollBar up arrow, the first line looks like there's some empty space above - which might be the result of confused internal state and incomplete cell re-use (didn't dig) But then the question is way too vague ..

Comment: @kleopatra, Thanks for the feedback. Yeah I too aware of some issues with this approach. Because the context for me of using this is a quite different (fixed no of visibile rows, fixed table height, etc) and it suits exactly for my purpose. I thought that giving my inputs may help the questioner to think in that direction for a better solution.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  ListView listView = new ListView();
    listView.setItems(listConetnt);

    EventHandler onePositionScrollEvent = (EventHandler<ScrollEvent>) event -> {
        int scrollIndex = 0;

        if (event.getDeltaY() > 0) {
            scrollIndex = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() - 1;
        } else {
            scrollIndex = listView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedIndex() + 1;
        }

        listView.getSelectionModel().select(scrollIndex);
    };

    listView.setOnScroll(onePositionScrollEvent);
```

Comment: This is really good. However, when I scroll I need to keep my last selection as I scroll and the way you commented selects an option when scrolling. Also the scrolling event won't trigger if the scroll is little which in my case is important. Thank you anyways.

Comment: I'm not sure about properly understand... do you want scroll list by one element without selection change?

Comment: Yes. When scrolling my only interest is to see the elements complete and not cut by half, but without changing selection.